# Vue changing a bool from true to false inside of an Axios API call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am using Vue.js and Axios to make an API call.
When the call returns I want to set a variable that is false to true temporarily.  I am using a SetTimeout to do this.  The issue I am running into is that unless I hard code the variable name Vue does not respond.

In my template

```
<i v-if="fnameEntered" id="fnameCheckPlacement" class="fnameCheck" class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="margin-right: 10%;"></i>
```

Then in my script

```
  methods: {
            submitFirstName: function(event){
                this.updateUserInfo(this.fname, "fname", this.fnameEntered);
            },
            updateUserInfo: function (val, field, checkMark) {
                axios.post('/userprofilepage', {
                    val: val,
                    field: field
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        let self = this;
                        setTimeout(function() {

                            self.checkMark = false;
                        }, 2000);
                        this.checkMark = true;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                    .finally(() => this.loading = false)
            },
        }
```

I am trying to pass `this.fnameEntered` as the variable `checkMark` into updateUserInfo.  When I hard code `this.fnameEntered = true` and `this.fnameEntered = false`. I get the result I want.

But, when I try to use "this.checkMark" or "self.checkMark" nothing happens. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: As you are passing the variable why are you using `this.checkMark` ? Shouldn't it be just `checkMark = false` ?

Comment: @gilango Already tried that and it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not updating because you are passing a boolean which is primitive data type. JavaScript always pass the primitive data types into function as value and not by reference. There are 2 ways you can make it work

1. Use `this.fnameEntered` inside your method
2. Change `this.fnameEntered` to an object as `this.fnameEntered = { value: false}` then use `checkMark.value = true` inside your method

Answer (score 1):

Naturally it's not going to work. When you pass `this.fnameEntered` into the method call, you no longer hold a reference to the original property `fnameEntered`, only a copy of the value it contained when you invoked the method. Furthermore, `this.checkMark` and `self.checkMark` will check for the *hard-coded* property name `checkMark`, which is completely different from the variable name `checkMark`.

If you want to retrieve a dynamic property name's value, you need to do the following:
 1. Pass in the name of the desired property as a string.
 2. Retrieve the value using the passed in property name.

This will look something like this:

```
methods: {
    submitFirstName: function(event){
        this.updateUserInfo(this.fname, "fname", "fnameEntered");
    },
    updateUserInfo: function (val, field, propertyName) {
        axios.post('/userprofilepage', {
            val: val,
            field: field
        })
            .then(response => {
                let self = this;
                setTimeout(function() {

                    self.$data[propertyName] = false;
                }, 2000);
                this.$data[propertyName] = true;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(() => this.loading = false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Missed by a minute :D

Comment: @gilango Your answer is still valuable by pointing out the option to pass in an _object_ as opposed to a _primitive_. I would suggest clarifying that the OP should avoid using `this.checkMark` if using your solution (I could see this being easily overlooked), and perhaps show example code, but otherwise your solution is still a constructive alternative to the one presented here :)